# How to auto terminate ProcessGroup output port?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have designed a process group with several output ports, but when I want to use them, I have to connect all output port to another processors, otherwise flowfiles accumulate in output port.
Is there any way to auto terminate output port for a process group like what we can do for processors by set *Automatically Terminate Relationships*?

I realized that flowfile expiration can be used to prevent accumulation of flowfile. But I am looking for better method.

Comment: No, just do with processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an output port then it is expected to be connected somewhere in order to be valid. If you aren't going to connect it somewhere, then you wouldn't have the port. You would just auto-terminate the processors before that, or send everything to a dead-end processor like UpdateAttribute that does nothing and is auto-terminated.

Comment: I am going to add these ProcessGroup to Nifi-Registry and use them somewhere else with different requirements. It would be very useful to have an option to auto terminate outputs for ProcessGroups.

Comment: You can still version control it with the output port being unconnected, or you can connect it to a processor outside the PG in your dev environment and when you version control it only captures what is in the PG